# git ls-tree: aggregate sibling paths into single hash?

Tags: git, hash, git-ls-tree

With `git ls-tree` I can get hash of some content inside repository by its commit.

Like:

```
git ls-tree HEAD path1 --object-only
hash1

git ls-tree HEAD path2 --object-only
hash2
```

Is there a way to aggregate hash that would represent all those paths (path1, path2) as a single hash instead of multiple?

If `path2` is inside `path1`, then it nicely aggregates and I only need to specify `path1`, but if `path2` is a sibling, I don't see a way to aggregate it. I could create combination of a string like `hash1-hash2`, but if there are many sibling paths, it would get pretty long fast.

Or maybe there is some other technique to get hash of multiples sibling paths in some aggregated hash?

**Update**

For example given this files/folders structure within git repo:

```
my-repo/
  other/
  src/
  my-file1.txt
  my-file2.txt
```

I want to have aggregated hash for `src` and two extra files `my-file1.txt` and `my-file2.txt`. So if any of those change, I would get new hash. Now I can't use parent dir as hash because I don't want to include `other` directory. Also `git ls-tree` does not allow to use repo root dir as a path (in this case `my-repo`).

Comment: I use it in check to know if my docker image needs to be rebuilt. If content used for image has not changed, I can reuse image from registry. Most of the content comes from one directory, but there are few files outside that directory that can have have effect on image built as well. So I would like to also know if those sibling files changed or not.

Comment: @eftshift0 I added an example what I would like to have aggregated hash for.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to workaround this by creating hard links to sibling files.

Like:

```
cd src
ln ../my-file1.txt my-file1.txt
ln ../my-file2.txt my-file2.txt
```

Its not ideal, but I had only few such files, so its not that big of a problem.

Also note, symbolic links won't work, because `git ls-tree` ignores it as it sees changes on real files only.